# How to use getBoundingClientRect with transform scale?

Tags: javascript, html, css, transform, getboundingclientrect

I have a div element which is scaled by 5 and has 64px width and height.
Now if I use `div.getBoundingClientRect` it doesn't work with transform scale meaning it still has the width and height of 64px even though it's scaled (can't really explain it better).
html:

```html
<div id=div style="transform: scale(5); width: 64px; height: 64px"></div>
```

js:

```js
function getMousePosition(e) {
  var offset = div.getBoundingClientRect();
  mouse = {
    x: e.pageX - offset.left,
    y: e.pageY - offset.top
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get the mouse position in a 64px div but ofc, it didn't work with transform scale.

Comment: It's because `transform` doesn't change `bounding box` of the element.

Comment: How can I fix this?

Comment: I lied, everything works as intended, I don't know what problem do you have

Comment: Evverything is working as I'd expect - you get the x and y within the expanded element. If you want to know what that would have been within the non scaled element you'll have to divide by the scale and adjust for the transform origin. Can you explain a bit more what the use case is?

Answer (score -1):

```js
function getMousePosition(e) {
  var offset = div.getBoundingClientRect();
  console.log(offset)
  mouse = {
    x: e.pageX - offset.left,
    y: e.pageY - offset.top
  }
}


document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('mousemove', getMousePosition)
```

```html
<div id=div style="transform: scale(5); width: 64px; height: 64px; background: red"></div>
```